# Is there a way to initialize member variables of an object at declaration in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I understand that member variables of a class are initialized inside the constructor, like this:

```
type
  TMyClass = class
  private
    FMyVariable: Integer;
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;

constructor TMyClass.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FMyVariable := 5;
end;
```

However, I'm curious to know if there's a way to initialize these member variables directly at their declaration, something akin to:

```
type
  TMyClass = class
  private
    FMyVariable: Integer = 5; // Is this possible in Delphi?
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;
```

Any insights, explanations, or best practices would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seems a bit too much of an opinion and discussion orientated question that is not a very good fit for SO.

Comment: I don't really see why this question was closed. I had no problem understanding it and it's a valid question to ask, especially if somebody comes from a different programming language background e.g. C++.

Comment: @dummzeuch me either, the worse i just found a solution using attribute ! but i can not share it here as the question is closed :(

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I made a workable solution and made the source available here: https://github.com/MagicFoundation/Alcinoe:

In the constant evolution of software development, we often find ourselves seeking ways to reduce boilerplate code and enhance the maintainability of our projects. One such instance where boilerplate can become cumbersome is in the initialization of class fields. The traditional method involves explicitly setting each field's value in the constructor, which can be tedious, especially for classes with numerous fields. Enter TALInit—a feature that allows automatic initialization of object fields based on their attributes.

**The Traditional Way**

In the typical approach, developers manually initialize object fields in the constructor. Take the following class as an example:

```
TAutoInitObject = class(TObject)
public
  CharValue: Char;
  ChildObject: TChildObject;
public
  constructor Create; virtual;
  destructor Destroy; override;
End;
```

Here, each field is initialized in the Create constructor:

```
  constructor TAutoInitObject.create(const aOwner: Tform1; const AAutoInit: Boolean);
  begin
    CharValue := 'A';
    ChildObject := TChildObject.create;
    ChildObject.Name := 'AnObject';
    ChildObject.Value := 12.2;
  end;
 
  destructor TAutoInitObject.Destroy;
  begin
    ALFreeandNil(ChildObject);
    inherited;
  end;
```

While this method offers precise control, it can become tedious for large classes with numerous fields.

**The TALInit Way**

Imagine having a mechanism that not only automates this but is also as fast as the traditional way - yes, you read that right. TALInit achieves this remarkable feat.

```
TAutoInitObject = class(TObject)
public
  [TALInit('A')]
  CharValue: Char;
  [TALInit('Name:AnObject;Value:12.2')]
  ChildObject: TChildObject;
End;
```

By using custom attributes, every field within the object can be automatically initialized based on its corresponding attribute. This eliminates the need for manually setting each field within the constructor. The above snippet showcases just how concise and readable object field initialization can become with TALInit.

**Performance**

One of the strongest advantages of using TALInit is its performance. When introducing automation, a natural concern is the overhead that might come with it. However, **TALInit is designed to be as efficient as the traditional way of initializing fields**. This means developers can enjoy the convenience without having to worry about any hidden costs in execution time.

Comment: "yes, you read that right. TALInit achieves this remarkable feat." this sounds like TV shop channel trying to sell you a cat in the bag. Your overblown class implementation (that holds redundant code for auto initialization) is still 30% faster with regular initialization than your automatic initialization. That is not a small difference. There is absolutely no advantage in initializing class through attributes comparing to usual way through constructor.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar  I appreciate the feedback regarding the tone of the post. The intention was to convey enthusiasm and introduce the concept in an engaging way. I understand how it may have come off as too promotional, and I'll take that into consideration in the future.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I'd like to clarify that there was an oversight in our demo regarding the traditional way of finalization. I've since rectified the error. If you can pull the latest updates from our GitHub repository, you'll find the updated benchmarks: With the auto-init method, 1,000,000 TAutoInitObject instances are created in 1463.24 ms, and with the classical method, it's 1449.78 ms. This difference is a mere 0.01x, which is negligible and virtually imperceptible, even in server-side contexts.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar The advantage of using attributes for initialization, from our perspective, lies mainly in the potential for reducing boilerplate code and enhancing code readability, especially for larger classes. While performance is crucial, TALInit also aims to provide developers with a more concise way to handle object field initialization. That said, the traditional method of initializing through the constructor will always have its place and might be preferable in many scenarios.

Comment: Seems like you want to make this a recommendation question for some library, which would be off topic.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan not at all, sorry that the description look like a little advertising but that not the case, it's just that I could not copy past the code as it's too much big. I made the code AFTER posting this question and it's answer the question

Comment: Even after the fix, there is still significant difference in performance. I removed value verification from the constructor as this is not something you would have in regular code  Auto initialization runs for 2100 ms and regular initialization for 1600 ms. I don't have a problem if you want to share attribute initialization approach (even though I don't personally find it more readable), but performance claims are simply not true.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar thank you for your insights. The performance difference you've observed is intriguing, as my benchmarks showed a narrower gap. Attribute-based approaches are typically 100 to 1000 times slower, so achieving a difference of just 0.01 to 0.10 is, from my perspective, a significant win. TALInit's primary design was for reducing boilerplate, but these performance results are a promising bonus. Hardware or Delphi versions might explain our differing results. I'll revisit my benchmarks and documentation based on your feedback

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar, I'd like to emphasize that the main purpose of using attributes in this context is specifically for a specialized "LOW CODE" framework. In many typical scenarios, I concur that the classical way, using constructors, remains the preferable and more straightforward method. The attribute-based approach serves a niche need, but certainly doesn't aim to replace the established best practices.

Comment: It's the same amount of code, just in a different place

Comment: My objections to your answer have nothing to do with the solution itself (it is easy to decide for anyone whether they like attribute based initialization or not), but the claims that it is as fast as regular initialization. While you (or anyone else) can decide that the performance penalty does not matter in their scenario, that does not change the fact __there is a performance penalty__ and that is contrary to what your answer is advertising.

Comment: I find initializing the fields / properties via attributes quite interesting for some scenarios, eg. configuration classes where I normally would have a default value declared which would then have to be initialized in the constructor. Doing that via attributes makes it easier to find those default values from the class declaration. I'm not sure I would want to use it anywhere else though, but that's probably a matter of personal taste or requirements (e.g. do those milliseconds for initialization really matter for the use case.)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, you're right that the total code might be similar in volume. However, the primary intent is to colocate the initialization values directly alongside their respective member declarations. This setup is particularly beneficial when dealing with classes that have numerous members. How many times have you had to navigate to the constructor and sift through the code to ensure no member was overlooked during initialization? When there are hundreds of members, such checks can be cumbersome. TALInit simplifies this process by keeping initialization close to declaration.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I understand your concerns regarding the performance claims. You're right; using direct memory manipulation like Pint64(Pointer(NativeInt(AInstance) + LRttiField.Offset))^ := ARttiInitValues[i].Int64Value; VS MyInt64Field := 55 could introduce a potential performance penalty. However, during my tests, particularly when instantiating 1,000,000 objects on my laptop, I genuinely didn't observe any significant difference. That said, I acknowledge that performance can vary based on hardware, especially concerning memory operations. I'll certainly revisit this point

Comment: @dummzeuch I completely agree with you. The main appeal of initializing fields via attributes is for scenarios like configuration classes, where default values need to be clearly seen directly within the class declaration. It provides a concise way to see defaults at a glance, improving maintainability and readability. As for performance, you're right – for individual object creation, we're discussing nanoseconds, not milliseconds! The impact on performance is truly negligible in most use cases. It really does boil down to personal preference and the specific requirements of a given project.

Comment: Placing initial values at the declaration is a reasonable argument, low code is not.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes I agree. For example, Java allows the setting up of the initial value of each member at their declaration. It's not unreasonable to desire placing the initial value close to its declaration. When I mention 'low code,' I'm referring to the idea of staying within the interface section and not delving into the implementation section. However, it's worth noting that this might not lead to a reduction in the amount of code in the end.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not possible in Delphi. The only member type of a class, that can be initialized in the declaration, are constants:

```
type
  TMyClass = class
  public
    const
      MY_PI = 3.00;
  end;
```

Everything else is automatically initialized to 0, NULL, '' or whatever the equivalent of zero is for this particular type is and can then be changed in the constructor.

Comment: in fact it's possible :) see my answer with attribute

Answer (score 2):

> I'm curious to know if there's a way to initialize these member variables directly at their declaration.

There is no way to do this.

Comment: in fact it's possible :) you can see my answer with attribute